# For loops and else statements in Python

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using some conditional for loops within the jinja2 template framework for python. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the same thing but outside of jinja2, similar to:

```
{% for i in a if i == 1 %}
  {{ i }}
{% else %}
  no items
{% endfor %}
```

When I try this in plain ol' python, it doesn't like it

```
>>> for i in a if i == 1:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
for i in a if i == 1:
    print i
else:
    print 'no matches found'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `else` blocks with loop statements. If the loop flow isn't disturbed by statements such as `break`, it falls to the `else` block. I included a simple **prime number finder** below:

```
 for n in range(2, 10):
     for x in range(2, n):
         if n % x == 0:
             print n, 'equals', x, '*', n/x
             break
     else:
         # loop fell through without finding a factor
         print n, 'is a prime number'
```

**Output:**

```
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

**Note:** If you combine `for` / `else` statements with list comprehensions you can accomplish what you want.
Simple list comprehension:

```
# For generating a list of odd numbers from 1 to 10
[n for n in range(1, 10) if n % 2 == 1]

# Generator version preventing evaluation of the whole list at once.
(n for n in range(1, 10) if n % 2 == 1)
```

That way you'll generate an `iterable` container with list comprehension method and iterate it using a `for` / `else` loop:

```
for n in [n for item_container if n == 1]
    # Do work
    pass
else:
    # Loop falls through if the flow isn't disturbed
    # Do some other work
    pass
```

**Edit:** What you are asking is simply checking whether an element is in a container or not and then executing statements. It is terribly inefficient. You can do that much faster using `set` data structure in `CPython`(Python's most common implementation).

- Your code has **O(n)** complexity at average and worst case.
- `set` member check will have **O(1)** at average and **O(n)** at worst(`dictionary` has a similar implementation).

So the following code will be much **faster**:

```
element = 9
container = set(range(1, 10))

print("Match Found." if element in container else "Match Not Found.")
```

For more information check below:

- [Python Control Flow](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)
- [Python List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- [Python Set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: Thanks, but nope :( The unique thing about the Jinja2 loop is that the else portion ONLY executes if there are zero matches to the conditional given in the for loop. So 'no items' is only executed if there is no i == 1. If there is a match in the for loop, the else portion is not executed at all.

Comment: @Chockomonkey You can do that too. I updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

You're already very close, all that is needed is a list comprehension that forms a list with only the values of `a` that are equal to 1.

In python the `for..else` statement [is valid](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) as well.

```
for i in [x for x in a if x == 1]:
    print i
else:
    print 'no matches found'
```

This will print all the values in `a` that are `1`, unless none were found. Then it prints `no matches found`

As mentioned by davidism, to prevent an intermediate evaluation of the entire list, you can use a generator instead of a LC:

```
for i in (x for x in a if x == 1):
    print i
else:
    print 'no matches found'
```

Comment: Wow, is this legit? I've never come across that statement.

Comment: @ToonAlfrink yes, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: I wish I could mark more than one answer as my answer, because this hit the nail on the head too. Thanks for the 4-line answer, i didn't know you could do this either. Your link to the naming convention question on for..else was also a very good read. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the values in a list:

```
items = [i for i in a if i == 1]
```

To print out, including a note if there are no matches:

```
for i in items:
    print i
if not items:
    print 'no matches found'
```